# How to nest a table within a table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've seen a similar topic, but not for my specific situation. I need to nest a table within the table and it will take up several cells, but when I try to nest a table it deletes the surrounding table at the same time. I included a picture of how it should look after my code and my code is how it looks currently. Can someone explain how this is done? Much appreciated.

```css
/* 
   CSS for Lounge Project 
   Filename: styles.css
   
   Author:   Justus Self
   Date:     3/21/17
   HTML5 and CSS3 Illustrated Unit I, Lounge Independent Project
*/

/*Reset Styles*/
html, body{
   font-size: 14px;
   width: 100%;
   }
a, body, footer, header, h1, h2, h3, img, li, nav, p, ul, table, tbody, td, tfoot, th, thead, tr{
   border: 0;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
img {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   width: auto;
}

/*Drink font colors*/

h2.green {
  color: green;
}
h2.blue {
  color: blue;
}
h2.purple {
  color: purple;
}
h2.red {
  color: red;
}
h2.yellow {
  color: gold;
}


/*center and border image*/

img.smlounge {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 3px solid;
  border-color: red;
}


/*Table styles*/

td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 1em ;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
td[colspan="2"] {
  width: 20%;
}
.drink-name {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Head First Lounge Elixirs</title>

  <!-- 
   Elixir page for Lounge Project 
   Filename: elixir.html
   
   Author:   Justus Self
   Date:     3/21/17
   HTML5 and CSS3 Illustrated Unit I, Lounge Independent Project
   -->

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../lounge.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Our Elixirs</h1>

  <h2 class="green">Green Tea Cooler</h2>
  <p>
    <img src="../images/green.jpg" alt="Green Tea Cooler" /> Chock full of vitamins and minerals, this elixir combines the healthful benefits of green tea with a twist of chamomile blossoms and ginger root.
  </p>
  <hr/>
  <h2 class="blue">Raspberry Ice Concentration</h2>
  <p>
    <img src="../images/lightblue.jpg" alt="Rasberry Ice Concentration" /> Combining raspberry juice with lemon grass, citrus peel and rosehips, this icy drink will make your mind feel clear and crisp.
  </p>
  <hr/>
  <h2 class="purple">Blueberry Bliss Elixir</h2>
  <p>
    <img src="../images/blue.jpg" alt="Blueberry Bliss Elixir" /> Blueberries and cherry essence mixed into a base of elderflower herb tea will put you in a relaxed state of bliss in no time.
  </p>
  <hr/>
  <h2 class="red">Cranberry Antioxidant Blast</h2>
  <p>
    <img src="../images/red.jpg" alt="Cranberry Antioxidant Blast" /> Wake up to the flavors of cranberry and hibiscus in this vitamin C rich elixir.
  </p>
  <hr/>
  <h2 class="yellow"><a name="Yellow">Lemon Breeze</a></h2>
  <p><img src="../images/yellow.gif" alt="Lemon Breeze Drink" /> The ultimate healthy drink, this elixir combines herbal botanicals, minerals, and vitamins with a twist of lemon into a smooth citrus wonder that will keep your immune system going all day
    and all night.
  </p>
  <hr/>
  <br/>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="6">Our Drink Prices</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Drink</th>
        <th colspan="2">Size</th>
        <th colspan="2">Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="drink-name">Green Tea Cooler</td>
        <td colspan="2">16 oz.</td>
        <td colspan="2">$3.75</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">24 oz.</td>
        <td colspan="2">$4.75</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="drink-name">Raspberry Ice Concentration</td>
        <td colspan="2">16 oz.</td>
        <td colspan="2">$3.75</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">24 oz.</td>
        <td colspan="2">$4.75</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="drink-name">Cranberry Antioxidant Blast</td>
        <td colspan="2">20 oz.</td>
        <td colspan="2">$4.75</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="drink-name">Lemon Breeze</td>
        <td>Iced</td>
        <td>16 oz.</td>
        <td>$3.75</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Frozen</td>
        <td>20 oz.</td>
        <td>$4.75</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p><a href="../lounge.html">Back to the Lounge</a></p>

  <footer>
    &#169;2016, Head First Online Lounge<br /> All trademarks and registered trademarks appearing on this site are the property of their respective owners.
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

[How the table should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RM2AS.png)

Comment: I don't understand your table looks pretty much the same as the picture?

Comment: In the image do you see the double border around some of the cells near the bottom of the table? That's a table nested within the original table. And I have to replicate that for this project.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below and change the CSS as per your need.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Head First Lounge Elixirs</title>

  <!-- 
   Elixir page for Lounge Project 
   Filename: elixir.html
   
   Author:   Justus Self
   Date:     3/21/17
   HTML5 and CSS3 Illustrated Unit I, Lounge Independent Project
   -->

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../lounge.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Our Elixirs</h1>

  <h2 class="green">Green Tea Cooler</h2>
  <p>
    <img src="../images/green.jpg" alt="Green Tea Cooler" /> Chock full of vitamins and minerals, this elixir combines the healthful benefits of green tea with a twist of chamomile blossoms and ginger root.
  </p>
  <hr/>
  <h2 class="blue">Raspberry Ice Concentration</h2>
  <p>
    <img src="../images/lightblue.jpg" alt="Rasberry Ice Concentration" /> Combining raspberry juice with lemon grass, citrus peel and rosehips, this icy drink will make your mind feel clear and crisp.
  </p>
  <hr/>
  <h2 class="purple">Blueberry Bliss Elixir</h2>
  <p>
    <img src="../images/blue.jpg" alt="Blueberry Bliss Elixir" /> Blueberries and cherry essence mixed into a base of elderflower herb tea will put you in a relaxed state of bliss in no time.
  </p>
  <hr/>
  <h2 class="red">Cranberry Antioxidant Blast</h2>
  <p>
    <img src="../images/red.jpg" alt="Cranberry Antioxidant Blast" /> Wake up to the flavors of cranberry and hibiscus in this vitamin C rich elixir.
  </p>
  <hr/>
  <h2 class="yellow"><a name="Yellow">Lemon Breeze</a></h2>
  <p><img src="../images/yellow.gif" alt="Lemon Breeze Drink" /> The ultimate healthy drink, this elixir combines herbal botanicals, minerals, and vitamins with a twist of lemon into a smooth citrus wonder that will keep your immune system going all day
    and all night.
  </p>
  <hr/>
  <br/>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="6">Our Drink Prices</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Drink</th>
        <th colspan="2">Size</th>
        <th colspan="2">Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="drink-name">Green Tea Cooler</td>
        <td colspan="2">16 oz.</td>
        <td colspan="2">$3.75</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">24 oz.</td>
        <td colspan="2">$4.75</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="drink-name">Raspberry Ice Concentration</td>
        <td colspan="2">16 oz.</td>
        <td colspan="2">$3.75</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">24 oz.</td>
        <td colspan="2">$4.75</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="drink-name">Cranberry Antioxidant Blast</td>
        <td colspan="2">20 oz.</td>
        <td colspan="2">$4.75</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="drink-name">Lemon Breeze</td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <table>
            <tr>

              <td>Iced</td>
              <td>16 oz.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Frozen</td>
              <td>20 oz.</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>$3.75</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>$4.75</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p><a href="../lounge.html">Back to the Lounge</a></p>

  <footer>
    &#169;2016, Head First Online Lounge<br /> All trademarks and registered trademarks appearing on this site are the property of their respective owners.
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is what happens when I try to do the code as well. When I implement your code it breaks off from the original table into it's own table without staying inside the confines of the original. Is there some way to edit this to make it behave like it does in the picture I provided?

Answer (score 1):

Nested like this

```css
/* 
   CSS for Lounge Project 
   Filename: styles.css
   
   Author:   Justus Self
   Date:     3/21/17
   HTML5 and CSS3 Illustrated Unit I, Lounge Independent Project
*/


/*Reset Styles*/

html,
body {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100%;
}

a,
body,
footer,
header,
h1,
h2,
h3,
img,
li,
nav,
p,
ul,
table,
tbody,
td,
tfoot,
th,
thead,
tr {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}


/*Drink font colors*/

h2.green {
  color: green;
}

h2.blue {
  color: blue;
}

h2.purple {
  color: purple;
}

h2.red {
  color: red;
}

h2.yellow {
  color: gold;
}


/*center and border image*/

img.smlounge {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 3px solid;
  border-color: red;
}


/*Table styles*/

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

td[colspan="2"] {
  width: 20%;
}

.drink-name {
  text-align: left;
}

.mintable {
  border-collapse: initial;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

tbody {
  border: solid black 1px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Head First Lounge Elixirs</title>

  <!-- 
   Elixir page for Lounge Project 
   Filename: elixir.html
   
   Author:   Justus Self
   Date:     3/21/17
   HTML5 and CSS3 Illustrated Unit I, Lounge Independent Project
   -->

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../lounge.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Our Elixirs</h1>

  <h2 class="green">Green Tea Cooler</h2>
  <p>
    <img src="../images/green.jpg" alt="Green Tea Cooler" /> Chock full of vitamins and minerals, this elixir combines the healthful benefits of green tea with a twist of chamomile blossoms and ginger root.
  </p>
  <hr/>
  <h2 class="blue">Raspberry Ice Concentration</h2>
  <p>
    <img src="../images/lightblue.jpg" alt="Rasberry Ice Concentration" /> Combining raspberry juice with lemon grass, citrus peel and rosehips, this icy drink will make your mind feel clear and crisp.
  </p>
  <hr/>
  <h2 class="purple">Blueberry Bliss Elixir</h2>
  <p>
    <img src="../images/blue.jpg" alt="Blueberry Bliss Elixir" /> Blueberries and cherry essence mixed into a base of elderflower herb tea will put you in a relaxed state of bliss in no time.
  </p>
  <hr/>
  <h2 class="red">Cranberry Antioxidant Blast</h2>
  <p>
    <img src="../images/red.jpg" alt="Cranberry Antioxidant Blast" /> Wake up to the flavors of cranberry and hibiscus in this vitamin C rich elixir.
  </p>
  <hr/>
  <h2 class="yellow"><a name="Yellow">Lemon Breeze</a></h2>
  <p><img src="../images/yellow.gif" alt="Lemon Breeze Drink" /> The ultimate healthy drink, this elixir combines herbal botanicals, minerals, and vitamins with a twist of lemon into a smooth citrus wonder that will keep your immune system going all day
    and all night.
  </p>
  <hr/>
  <br/>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="6">Our Drink Prices</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Drink</th>
        <th colspan="2">Size</th>
        <th colspan="2">Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="drink-name">Green Tea Cooler</td>
        <td colspan="2">16 oz.</td>
        <td colspan="2">$3.75</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">24 oz.</td>
        <td colspan="2">$4.75</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="drink-name">Raspberry Ice Concentration</td>
        <td colspan="2">16 oz.</td>
        <td colspan="2">$3.75</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">24 oz.</td>
        <td colspan="2">$4.75</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="drink-name">Cranberry Antioxidant Blast</td>
        <td colspan="2">20 oz.</td>
        <td colspan="2">$4.75</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="drink-name">Lemon Breeze</td>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">
          <table class="mintable">
            <tr>
              <td>Iced</td>
              <td>16 oz.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Frozen</td>
              <td>20 oz.</td>

            </tr>

          </table>

        </td>
        <td>
          <table class="mintable">
            <tr rowspan="2" colspan="2">
              <td>$4.75</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>$3.75</td>
            </tr>
          </table>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <td></td>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <br>
  <p><a href="../lounge.html">Back to the Lounge</a></p>

  <footer>
    &#169;2016, Head First Online Lounge<br /> All trademarks and registered trademarks appearing on this site are the property of their respective owners.
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's close, but the border still doesn't fit the same as it does in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this (of course you'll need to fix the font size and styling, and do the other side too. Ok try this. you still need to fix the font sizing

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="6">Our Drink Prices</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Drink</th>
    <th colspan="2">Size</th>
    <th colspan="2">Price</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="drink-name">Green Tea Cooler</td>
    <td colspan="2">16 oz.</td>
    <td colspan="2">$3.75</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">24 oz.</td>
    <td colspan="2">$4.75</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="drink-name">Raspberry Ice Concentration</td>
    <td colspan="2">16 oz.</td>
    <td colspan="2">$3.75</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">24 oz.</td>
    <td colspan="2">$4.75</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="drink-name">Cranberry Antioxidant Blast</td>
    <td colspan="2">20 oz.</td>
    <td colspan="2">$4.75</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="drink-name">Lemon Breeze</td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" class="nested">

    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr><td>Iced</td><td>16 oz</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Frozen</td><td>20 oz</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>


    </td>

    <td>$3.75</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>


    <td>$4.75</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
/* 
   CSS for Lounge Project 
   Filename: styles.css

   Author:   Justus Self
   Date:     3/21/17
   HTML5 and CSS3 Illustrated Unit I, Lounge Independent Project
*/

/*Reset Styles*/
html, body{
   font-size: 14px;
   width: 100%;
   }
a, body, footer, header, h1, h2, h3, img, li, nav, p, ul, table, tbody, td, tfoot, th, thead, tr{
   border: 0;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
img {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   width: auto;
}

/*Drink font colors*/

h2.green {
  color: green;
}
h2.blue {
  color: blue;
}
h2.purple {
  color: purple;
}
h2.red {
  color: red;
}
h2.yellow {
  color: gold;
}


/*center and border image*/

img.smlounge {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 3px solid;
  border-color: red;
}


/*Table styles*/

td, th, td td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 1em ;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:100%
}
table table{
  margin:1%;
  width:98%;

}
table table td{
  width:50%;
}
table table tr, table table tbody{
  width:100%
}
.nested{padding:0;}
td[colspan="2"] {
  width: 20%;
}
.drink-name {
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: That's what happens when I try to do this as well. It's still not quite the same as the example.

Comment: I don't want to just "do it for you" because it looks like you're supposed to be learning it. Use that table structure, but add more nested css styles to make it right. So you'll need table td table td to target the cells inside of the nested table

Comment: It's not doing it for me if you tell me how to do it. Like can you tell me what I'm supposed to change? The border? The font size? I've done the rest of this project by myself I'm just hung up on this last little thing.

Comment: specifically see the nested table styles table table and table table td. You have padding on your table cell which is why the nested table is not filling the entire width of the cell.

Comment: Since you didn't include the CSS in the original post I don't know what you really did. Since the padding is set to 0 for the .nested shouldn't it be closer to the other border than it is?

Comment: I updated all of your css and just pasted it all back here. .nested is for the first table cell which in your CSS you had set to have some padding. I set it back to 0 by putting a speciall class on that cell and setting the padding to 0. That's the nested class. Then, inside that I have the nested table with a width of 98% and a margin of 1%. That's what you need to fiddle with to get the border to be a little closer if you want. So instead of 98% and 1% you could make it 99% and .5%;